# WCF Service in Windows 8 App (service must always work)

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-8, windows-8.1

In my Windows 8 Application I need a WCF Service which will work all time. For example: User installed my Application and ran it, after that service must start and work all time, and must work even if User closed the Application. Also WCF Service must start at system startup. How can I do this?

Comment: You're describing a windows service , WCF self host will close as soon as you close the app unless you host it in a windows service

Comment: I agree with you that it looks like Windows Service, but unfortunately I can't install Windows Service from Windows 8 Metro App

Comment: may be you can create a package which contains your metro app and the windows service which wouldn't be visible to the user , it's just there

Comment: Not possible. So called service will work till app is running. Once app is closed, service will die. Win Store apps are sandboxed so you can not modify your system outside boundary of your app.